# Cast string array elements to byte array in java

Tags: java, arrays

I have a string array of form:

```
String[] s = {0x22, 0xD2, 0x01}
```

Now I have to convert it to byte array form like:

```
byte[] bytes = {(byte)0x22, (byte)0xD2, (byte)0x01}
```

It can be done in single line in c# but how to do it in Java as I have to append `bytes` array to another array of same kind and format.

Here I have included some part of the code as I can't include whole code:

```
String sr = "22D201";
String[] s = {sr.substring(0, 2),sr.substring(2, 4),sr.substring(4)};
byte[] ret = new byte[]{(byte)0x2C, (byte)0x04, (byte)0x01, (byte)0x67, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x3D};
```

Now I have to append `byte[] bytes` to `byte[] ret` but I can't as array is in the form of String that is `String[] s`. So how to covert `String[] s` so that I can add it to `byte[] ret`.

Comment: This `String[] s = {0x22, 0xAC, 0xFF};` is not valid Java: "incompatible types: int can not be converted to String". Plus, `AC` and  `FF` are to large for a byte.

Comment: Plese [edit] your question and include your real code.

Comment: Hey guys thanks and I got this. I used this method and it's working.   `public static byte[] hexStringToByteArray(String s) {  int len = s.length();  byte[] data = new byte[len / 2];  for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 2) {  data[i / 2] = (byte) ((Character.digit(s.charAt(i), 16) << 4)+Character.digit(s.charAt(i+1), 16));  }  return data;  }`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`String.getBytes();`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes%28%29).

You can also initialize a `String` using a byte array and a specified encoding scheme:

`String s = new String(new byte[]{ /* Bytes data. */}, "UTF-8");`

For an array of `Strings`, each individual String's byte array could therefore be processed as follows:

```
for(final String s : lStrings) {
     byte[] lBytes = s.getBytes();
}
```

If you wanted to make a contiguous array of these types, you could use a [`ByteArrayOutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html).

```
ByteArrayOutputStream b = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
for(final String s : lStrings) {
    b.write(s.getBytes());
}
final byte[] lTotalBytes = b.toByteArray();
/* Make sure all the bytes are written. */
b.flush();
/* Close the stream once we're finished. */
b.close();
```

Comment: The OP asks about `String[]` (even though he doesn't have any), not `String`.

Comment: Thanks for your advice! Hopefully it's fixed up now.